# Recovering system and data

Tags: partitioning, backup

Following an update released by Windows I lost my Ubuntu path.
Now I reinstalled Ubuntu in the system partition because of this false manipulation I lost the software installed before.

I've never created a restore point and that I had 18.04 and now I have 16.04. I have three partitions:

- 1 for Ubuntu
- 1 for Windows
- 1 for `home` (personal data)

In a clearer way, I am looking to recover my old system with all my personal data and files system.

The home partition still exists but I have a few files in the WWW folder of LAMP installation which contains my very important data which i lost.
Is there a way to recover the WWW folder?

Comment: Why do you mean by **ubuntu path**  ? If you mean the grub menu , you could launch it via the system boot menu (F12 in some motherboards ).And there's a nice program for recovering the lost files named [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download).You have to use **PhotoRec** .But note that it cannot find the name and path of the lost file,just contents. It supports almost 340 file formats.I've tested it and it works nicely.But you have to recover the files in a partition other than where they were.And don't forget to select the file formats you want manually in the procedure.

Comment: And because it cannot recover the filenames and paths , you won't be able to construct your former filesystem as it were.But at least you can recover your videos , images , PDFs and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure what "*recover my old system by date*" means. Are you asking about an OSX Time-Machine-like behavior? Or something else?

Comment: In a clearer way, I am looking to recover my old system with all my personal data and files system

Comment: Comments are intended to help you improve your question, not for conversation. Please make clarifications [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1253036/edit), not in comments. Aren't your personal files in your /home partition? Or did you somehow destroy that partition? Reinstalling Ubuntu should have overwritten all your system files...but that depends upon the install method you chose. How did you reinstall Ubuntu? Did you previously have some kind of backup method in place to recover from?